# Usage of queues in haskell (module)

Tags: haskell, module, queue

i have a question regarding this Haskell code:

```
module Queue (Queue, emptyQueue, queueEmpty, enqueue, dequeue, front) where

newtype Queue a = MakeQ([a])

emptyQueue :: Queue a
emptyQueue = MakeQ([])

queueEmpty :: Queue a -> Bool
queueEmpty (MakeQ(q)) = null q

enqueue :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
enqueue x (MakeQ(q)) = MakeQ(q ++ [x])

dequeue :: Queue a -> Queue a
dequeue (MakeQ(x:q)) = MakeQ(q)

front :: Queue a -> a
front (MakeQ(x:q)) = x
```

I know how a queue generally works and what each of the operations mainly does. My first problem is that i don't know how to use the operations in hugs. How do i create a empty queue or put an element in it after i created it? I tried several commands but all of them resulted in error messages, i.e. Make([]), emptyQueue [] ... I know that those commands are very naive, but i am absolutly not familiar with Haskell and need it only for 2 weeks or so.

Second question is regarding the "MakeQ" itself. This is just a declaration for a name for our operation, correct? Or is it a static Haskell command? Imo it could be also "QQQ" or whatever. I can't really test whether this would crash the programm or not because i don't know how to use this module.

Even if my question seem kind of stupid, i would be really happy if someone could give me an explanation or hints...

Comment: 2 notes. First, you have some superfluous parens. Anytime you write `MakeQ(blahblah)`, replace that with `MakeQ blahblah` for more idiomatic Haskell. Second, `++ [x]` is inefficient. If you are interested in efficiency, check out [Idiomatic efficient Haskell append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188286/idiomatic-efficient-haskell-append) (or just skip to, imho, the best answer, [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`emptyQueue` by itself is an empty queue; you don't have to pass any parameters to it.

`MakeQ` is just an arbitrary name, you're right; it could be anything (as long as you changed all the other uses of it). In this case, it's the *constructor* for `Queue`: if `xs` is a list of `a` values (i.e. has type `[a]`), then `MakeQ xs` is a `Queue a`. However, the module does not export `MakeQ`, so you can't use it from outside — it's used as part of the implementation, and hidden to maintain an abstraction; it could easily be rewritten in terms of another, non-list structure without breaking any code that uses the module.

Operations on the queue are done, not by updating an existing queue in-place, but by *transforming* a queue into new queues. For instance, if `a` is an `Int`, and `q` is a `Queue Int`, then `enqueue a q` is another `Queue Int` with `a` added to the back. Similarly, if `q` is a `Queue Int`, then `dequeue q` is another `Queue Int` without the front element, and `front q` is the front element itself (an `Int`).

Also, note that Hugs is not maintained any more; you should consider installing the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/), which is based on the GHC compiler. It contains an "interpreter" program just like Hugs, so it's not just a standard compiler.

Here's an example of how this queue module could be used from an interactive prompt:

```
GHCi> let q = emptyQueue :: Queue Int
GHCi> let q1 = enqueue 42 q
GHCi> front q1
42
GHCi> let q2 = enqueue 43 q1
GHCi> front q2
43
GHCi> front (dequeue q2)
42
```

If you're trying to maintain a queue throughout the execution of a program, then you probably want to use the *state monad*, which is a lot less scary than it sounds. :) I would recommend reading [*Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), which is an excellent Haskell tutorial covering, among many other things, the state monad.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot! I will follow your advice and check out the Learn you a Haskell page. Thank you! :)