# Finding mean of list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I think my code to find the mean of a list (of integers) works ok, but has a problem. This is my code

```
listlen xs = if null xs
             then 0
             else 1 + (listlen (tail xs))

sumx xs = if null xs
         then 0
         else (head xs) + sumx (tail xs)

mean xs = if null xs
          then 0
          else (fromIntegral (sumx xs)) / (fromIntegral (listlen xs))
```

my mean function has to go through the list twice. Once to get the sum of the elements, and once to get the number of elements. Obviously this is not great.

I would like to know a more efficient way to do this (using elementary Haskell - this is a a question from **Real World Haskell** chapter 3.)

Comment: You could use an accumulator to store the length.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @simonzack is alluding to is that you should write `listlen` and `sumx` as *folds*.

Here is `listlen` written as a fold:

```
listlen :: [a] -> Int
listlen xs = go 0 xs                 -- 0 = initial value of accumulator
  where go s [] = s                  -- return accumulator
        go s (a:as) = go (s+1) as    -- compute the next value of the accumulator
                                     -- and recurse
```

Here `s` is an accumulator which is passed from one iteration of the helper function `go` to the next iteration. It is the value returned when the end of the list has been reached.

Writing `sumx` as a fold will look like:

```
sumx :: [a] -> Int
sumx xs = go 0 xs
  where go s [] = s
        go s (a:as) = go ... as      -- flll in the blank ...
```

The point is that given two folds you can always combine them so they are computed together.

```
lenAndSum :: [a] -> (Int,Int)
lenAndSum xs = go (0,0) xs             -- (0,0) = initial values of both accumulators
  where go (s1,s2) [] = (s1,s2)        -- return both accumulators at the end
        go (s1,s2) (a:as) = go ... as  -- left as an exercise
```

Now you have computed both functions with one traversal of the list.

Answer (score 6):

I like the other answers here. But I don't like that they write their recursion by hand. There are lots of ways to do this, but one handy one is to reuse the `Monoid` machinery we have in place.

```
Data.Monoid Data.Foldable> foldMap (\x -> (Sum x, Sum 1)) [15, 17, 19]
(Sum {getSum = 51}, Sum {getSum = 3})
```

The first part of the pair is the sum, and the second part is the length (computed as the sum of as many `1`s as there are elements in the list). This is a quite general pattern: many statistics can actually be cast as monoids; and pairs of monoids are monoids; so you can compute as many statistics about a thing as you like in one pass using `foldMap`. You can see another example of this pattern in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25534690/791604), which is where I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Define a helper function that only goes through once:

```
lengthAndSum xs = if null xs
                  then (0,0)
                  else let (a,b) = lengthAndSum(tail xs) in (a + 1, b + head xs)

mean xs = let (a, b) = lengthAndSum xs in (fromIntegral b / fromIntegral a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, there's an idea: a function that takes a bunch of monoids and applies each to a list, all at the same time. But that can come later!

I think what you'll need is a fold and a tuple for a good speed:

```
avg :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
avg []   = error "Cannot take average of empty list"
avg nums = let (sum,count) = foldr (\e (s,c) -> (s+e,c+1)) (0,0)  nums
            in sum / count
```

I've tried this out, and it's decently speedy in GHCi, though It may not be the best. I thought up a recursive method, too, though it requires a helper function:

```
avg :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
avg []     = error "Cannot take average of empty list"
avg nums = let (sum, count) = go nums
            in sum / count
    where go [] = (0,0)
          go (x:xs) = let (sum',count') =  go xs
                       in (sum' + x, count' + 1)
```

Then again, that's *really* slow. Painfully slow.

Looking at your solution, that's alright, but it's not really idiomatic Haskell. `if` statements within functions tend to work better as pattern matches, especially if the `Eq` class instance isn't defined for such-and-such a datatype. Furthermore, as my example illustrated, *folds are beautiful*! They allow Haskell to be lazy and therefore are faster. That's my feedback and my suggestion in response to your question.