# Average of user input

Tags: function, haskell, average

I want to take the user input of a list of numbers and find the average. However, after looking for examples I have not found any that seems to match what I am doing because I can have from 2 - 100 numbers in a list. Any help/advice is appreciated.

Below is my working code as is.

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter how many numbers:"
  listlen <- getLine 
  if ((read listlen) <= 100) -- read converts a string to a number
  then do  

  putStrLn "Enter a String of numbers:"
  --numberString <- getLine

  numberString<- getLine
  let ints = map read (words numberString)  :: [Int]
  putStrLn("The List: " ++(numberString))

  putStrLn("The average: ")
  putStrLn("Number of values greater than average: ")

  else do
    putStrLn " Error: listlen must be less than or = to 100"
    main
```

Comment: So, what did you find that looked close but not a perfect match? Why do you think it won't work for you? Many people here could just write a solution for you, but to help you learn it's important to see what you're thinking and what you've tried.

Comment: I have tried the following: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199004/finding-mean-of-list-in-haskell
http://haskellsolutions.blogspot.com/2009/02/finding-average-of-three-numbers-in.html -- However dont know how to use that for up to 100 numbers that could be inputted

Comment: I have looked at just about all of the Haskell average related posts on here and none seem to have the length based on user input.. so I cant hard code the length.

Comment: That first link would work just fine for a list of any size, whether given by the user or not.

Comment: Oh, I must be super confused then. So after re working the code is this more on the right track now?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. It might be more appropriate to ask your professor or TA for help.

Comment: @Strom Thats why I am here.. my professor has tried to help and he doesnt know. He assigned all of us a different language to learn and only 2 of us got Haskell along with the professor not knowing it we dont have a TA.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is homework, but homework can be really tough when you have to do it in Haskell. I'll try to explain step by step how you can do.

## Good to know

First, Haskell is functional. You can find different defintions of "functional", but basically you can think of it as a property of the language: everything is constant (no side effect).

Second, you can start a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) by typing `ghci` in a terminal:

```
jferard@jferard-Z170XP-SLI:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set +m -- enable parsing of multiline commands
Prelude> -- type the expression you want to evaluate here
```

## Recursion

How do you compute the sum of the elements of a list? In an imperative language, you will do something like that (Python like):

```
s = 0
for every x in xs:
    s <- s + x
```

But `s` is not constant. It's updated on every iteration until we get the sum. Can we reformulate the algorithm to avoid this mutation? Fortunately yes. Here's the key idea:

```
sum [x] = x
sum [x1, ..., xn] = x1 + sum [x2, ..., xn]
```

With a little imagination, you can say that `sum [] = 0`. So we can write it in Haskell:

```
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs

-- sum [1, 2, 3, 5] == 11
```

`(x:xs)` means: `x` (the `head`) followed by the list `xs` (the `tail`). If you have understood that, you know how we can avoid side effects in many situations: just call another function to do the rest of the job. (Note: if you know about the stack, you can imagine what happens under the hood.)

Now, how do you compute the length of a list? In a Python-like language, you'd do something like (forget `len(..)`):

```
l = 0
for every x in xs:
    l <- l + 1
```

Again, with a recursive definition, you have:

```
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs

-- len [1, 2, 3, 5] == 4
```

## Folds

Computing sum and length is so common that they are built-in functions in Haskell. But there is something more important: if you examine the two functions carefully, you'll notice this pattern:

```
f [] = <initial value>
f (x:xs) = g(f xs, x)
```

For `sum`, initial value is `0` and `g(f xs, x) = x + f xs`. For `length`,  initial value is `0` and `g(f xs, x) = 1 + f xs`. This pattern is so common that Haskell has a built-in function (actually several built-in functions) for it: `foldl`. `foldl` takes a function, an initial value and a list and returns the function repeatedly applied to the previous result and the current element, until the list is consumed. You can think of the function as the the body of the loop:

```
sum xs = foldl (+) 0 xs
```

(Note on curryfication: 1. You will maybe learn some day that Haskell functions always take one argument, but that's not the point here. 2. You can remove xs on both sides: `sum = foldl (+) 0`)

```
Prelude> foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3,5]
11 -- (((0+1)+2)+3)+5
```

With `scanl`, you can in some way "debug" the `foldl`:

```
Prelude> scanl (+) 0 [1,2,3,5]
[0,1,3,6,11]
```

`length` is more tricky, since you don't have a built-in function `g(f xs, x) = 1 + f xs`. You can use a [lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Haskell): `\acc x -> 1 + acc` where `acc` is the current value:

```
length xs = foldl (\acc x -> 1 + acc) 0 xs
```

## Your question

### Average

Let's try to write `average` with the built-in `sum` and `length` functions:

```
Prelude> average xs = sum xs / length xs

<interactive>:1:14: error:
    • Could not deduce (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
    ...
```

What does that mean? I won't get into details, but you have to know that Haskell is very strict with numbers. You can't divide two integers and expect a float result without a little work.

```
Prelude> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

This means that `/` will take `Fractional`s. Thus, the work is: cast integers into `Fractional`s.

```
average xs = fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)

-- average [1, 2, 3, 5] == 2.75
```

### Number of values greater than average

Now, the number of values greater than the mean. In a Python-like langage, you'll write:

```
c = 0
for every x in xs:
    if x > avg:
        c <- c + 1
```

Let's try the recursive method:

```
gtAvg [] = 0
gtAvg (x:xs) = (if x>avg then 1) + sum xs -- WRONG
```

You see that there is something missing. In the imperative version, if `x <= avg`, we simply do nothing (and thus do not update the value). Here, we must return something:

```
gtAvg [] = 0
gtAvg (x:xs) = (if x>avg then 1 else 0) + gtAvg xs
```

But where does the `avg` value come from? We need to precompute it. Let's define a function that takes `avg` as an argument:

```
gtAvg' [] _ = 0
gtAvg' (x:xs) avg = (if fromIntegral x>avg then 1 else 0) + gtAvg' xs avg

-- gtAvg' [1, 2, 3, 5] (average [1, 2, 3, 5]) == 2
```

And then:

```
gtAvg xs = gtAvg' xs (average xs)

-- gtAvg [1, 2, 3, 5] == 2
```

Obviously, this is more simple with a `foldl`:

```
gtAvg xs = foldl (\acc x -> if fromIntegral x>average xs then acc+1 else acc) 0 xs
```

## More (map, filter and list comprehension)

When we are on the basics of Haskell, you may need three more constructs.

### Filter

First, a `filter`:

```
Prelude> filter (>2.75) [1, 2, 3, 5]
[3.0,5.0]
```

If you take the length of that list, you get the number of elements greater than the average:

```
gtAvg xs = length $ filter (\x -> fromIntegral x >average xs) xs
```

(Or with a composition of functions: `length $ filter ((> average xs).fromIntegral) xs`) Don't be disturbed by the `$` sign: it means that the right side of the expression (`filter...`) is one block, like if it were in parenthesis.

### Map

Second, `map` applies a function to every element of a list and returns the list of mapped elements. For instance, if you want to some squares of elements of a list:

```
Prelude> sum $ map (**2)  [1, 2, 3, 5]
39.0
```

You can use it like that:

```
gtAvg xs = length $ filter (>average xs) $ map fromIntegral xs
```

It converts elements to `Fractional`, then it applies the filter.

### List comprehension

Third, you can have `filter` and a `map` with a list comprehension:

```
gtAvg xs = length [x | x<-xs, fromIntegral x>average xs]
```

I left a lot of things aside and made probably approximations, but now you should have the basic knowledge to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
listlen :: [a] -> Int
listlen xs = go 0 xs                 -- 0 = initial value of accumulator
  where go s [] = s                  -- return accumulator
        go s (a:as) = go (s+1) as    -- compute the next value of the accumulator
sumx :: [a] -> Int
sumx xs = go 0 xs
  where go s [] = s
        go s (a:as) = go ... as      -- flll in the blank ...                                     -- and recurse
lenAndSum :: [a] -> (Int,Int)
lenAndSum xs = go (0,0) xs             -- (0,0) = initial values of both accumulators
  where go (s1,s2) [] = (s1,s2)        -- return both accumulators at the end
        go (s1,s2) (a:as) = go ... as  -- left as an exercise                                    

main = do

  putStrLn "Enter how many numbers:"
  listlen <- getLine 
  if ((read listlen) <= 100) -- read converts a string to a number
  then do  

  putStrLn "Enter a String of numbers:"
  --numberString <- getLine

  numberString<- getLine
  let ints = map read (words numberString)  :: [Int]
  putStrLn("The List: " ++(numberString))



  putStrLn("The average: ")
  putStrLn("Number of values greater than average: ")

  else do
    putStrLn " Error: listlen must be less than or = to 100"
    main`enter code here`
```

Comment: Sure, you're on the right track. There are valid ways to fill in those blanks that will answer your question (you'll have to fix the types, though). Also, be careful about plagiarism: while Stack Overflow doesn't mind if you use code from its answers, both Stack Overflow's licensing and your professor will require you to cite any code you use that is not your own. Plus, you already think you know the length of the list, so you don't necessarily need to compute it.